# EXCEL 2013 : set the name of variable from value of cells

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have set the name `P1A_FO_DESIGN` on a cell `A1` that countains the value `5.12`
I have set another cell `C10` with this value: `=("="&A10&"_"&B10&"_"&C8)`

`A10` contains `P1A`

`B10` contains `FO`

`C8` contains `DESIGN`

the value of `C10` is `=P1A_FO_DESIGN` but I would like it to display 5.12
How do I acheive it please?
Regards

Comment: Instead of doing named ranges which require an `INDRECT` formula (which is volatile) to look up their values, I would highly recommend creating a table that has the built variables names and their associated values so can you just do a `VLOOKUP` instead.  It will also be easier to maintain and update the table rather than continuing to make adjustments to named ranges.

Comment: thank you for this tip but I'm not sure I understand what you are proposing

Comment: ok I did the vlookup thing and it is easier to build but I found some constraints on this functions (data need to be ordered)

Answer (score 4):

Use `=INDIRECT()` formula:

```
=INDIRECT(A10&"_"&B10&"_"&C8)
```

This will evaluate to `=INDIRECT("P1A_FO_DESIGN")` Which will further evaluate to point to the cell with that Name.

Comment: Not sure that you need the additional quotation marks - it seems `=INDIRECT(A10&"_"&B10&"_"&C8)` would suffice from a quick test.

Comment: Right on. I tested and thought I needed them, but yea... because it's coming in from other cell values it will already be interpreted as a string. I will update the answer. Thanks!